# Language: How to explain someone not to use the word "command"?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

It's been a while I posted a question. Maybe this one belongs to *Programmers* or *Meta*, not sure.

Right now, I'm at university in my first year civil engineer. We have some programming courses where we learn Java in order to acquire the basic concepts of programming and train algorithmic thinking. Almost all my fellow students are unfamiliar with programming. I'm experienced and people do ask questions from time to time to me about their programming problems. While explaining their problem or while asking for solutions, they really often use the word *"command"*. I noticed that, in most cases, they are referring to what we call *statements*. My problem is that the word *command* really sounds bad and is in my opinion wrong as well, in this context. So, my question is: how do I explain them not to use *commands*, but rather something like *instructions*, *statements*, *expressions*, *declarations*, *operations*? How to explain that you do not program *commands*?

Sentences I hear frequently:

> *Which commands do I need?*
>   *What does this command do?*

---

Or am I the only one that thinks *command* is wrong? If so, please explain.

Comment: "Command" is fine.  I have words I prefer not to use too, but the only *legitimate* reason to tell other people not to use them is if they're ambiguous.  "Command" isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask them to be more specific for sake of professionalism.
A car is not a truck or not a van - and there are also bikes and bicycles and other things you could drive...

I would ask for being more specific EVERY time until they change their behaviour. You can lead them to the specific expression, but they should make the step to say it from their own. Otherwise they don't make an effort, because they count on you to help them.

Comment: +1: I like this. :) However, I'm going to wait for other answers, but this one is definitely a good one.